# Why java.util.InputMismatchException?

Tags: java

I'm trying to handle an exception but I receive something else. I dont know why I receive this.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:939)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1594)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2258)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2212)
    at P4.main(P4.java:28)
```

I want to handle ArrayOutOfBoundsException.
Thank you!

```
public class P4 {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner keyboard=new Scanner(System.in);
        ArrayList <Double> sir = new ArrayList<Double>();
        System.out.println("Please insert doubles: ");
        do {
            double x=keyboard.nextDouble();
            sir.add(x);
        }while(keyboard.hasNextDouble());
        System.out.println("Elements in the array are: " + sir);
        System.out.println("Enter the index of the required element: ");
        try {
            int element = keyboard.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Element in the given index is :: "+sir.get(element));
        } catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
            System.out.println("The index you have entered is invalid");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [InputMismatchException Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11270048/inputmismatchexception-error)

Comment: My class isnt named InputMismatchException.

Comment: "I want to handle ArrayOutOfBoundsException" you're not *getting* an ArrayOutOfBoundsException.

Comment: I should get it after I read the index value.

Comment: But you're not. You're failing when you try to read the index.

Comment: You are getting downvotes because you show an Java exception that shows an instance of an `InputMismatchExceptio`, while the answer you added shows you having a different problem

Comment: I was getting that error until I modified from ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException to IndexOutOfBoundsException. I don't know why I was getting that error.

Answer (score -1):

I modified from `catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e)` to
`catch(IndexOutOfBoundsException e)` . This is the answer.